# Kept working after rebasing, without git rebase --continue

Tags: git, github

I rebased master at a feature branch, resolved all conflicts; and kept on working and made a few commits.

While continuing to work and making commits on my feature branch, I never ran `git rebase --continue`.

If I run `git rebase --continue` now, it's telling me that there is nothing left to stage, and run `git add` in case I forgot it. Also I can `git rebase --skip` to skip the commit.

When I run `git add .` nothing happens, and `git status` is showing that there is nothing to commit, and the working tree is clean.

Currently I need to checkout to master, and pull from origin to fetch the latest updates. But if I switch branches now, I will lose the work that I've done.

How could I resolve this? Appreciate any input I could get.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `git rebase --abort` to halt the rebase and delete every change you made. If your changes are not many then this is the way to go, otherwise if you made a ton of changes and feel losing them isn't the right choice, I will try to think of an alternative.

Best

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this "you're still editing" notice is standard in this scenario (where you resolve a conflict, insert some extra commits before continuing with the rebase). I think it's a reminder to check the status (as you have done). If you just `git rebase --continue` a second time, git will indeed continue.

I hope you committed your conflict resolution before adding more commits, however. Otherwise you may have mixed changes into that commit. If so you might need to do an interactive rebase `git rebase -i`, edit that commit, and split those changes out again. (I find `git gui` is very useful for that.)